# Basic Auth URL Parsing

Tags: php, http-basic-authentication

We have a new b2b vendor that wants to use basic auth via URL.

They want to authenticate like this:

```
  //URL coming into our server
  http://usernametext:passwordtext@our.company.com/listener.php
```

How can I get the username and password from the URL via my listener.php script?

I have tried setting basic auth headers per the php man page but it pops up a login box, which is not what I need, since these are web services talking to each other, not people:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
     header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
     header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
     echo '<response><error>No username and password found</error></response>';
     exit;
 } else {

   //process request if username & password are legit

}
```

Comment: Using that URL style should present the username and password as Basic Auth credentials. This is a function of whatever software is making the request.  Your server needs to be configured to accept (and pass to your application) the credentials received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These [should](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) wind up in the variables `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`. You won't see them in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or anything.

Comment: It was a server configuration issue. I needed to compile the Apache module in my PHP. Once I did that, the $_SERVER array contained $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] Thanks